# Batch for each line in directory with spaces

Tags: batch-file, dos, spaces

I'm trying to create a batch file that compresses all folders within the main folder to individual zip files with the same name as the subfolders.

Example folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

So in the main folder, zips need to appear with the exact same name and contents as the subfolders.

The code I have right now is posted below. The problem occurs because I have to quote pathnames because they contain spaces and therefore `"%CD%\folders.txt"` in line 4 isn't parsed as filename, but as litteral input string. How can I get this to work?

P.s. I don't require a temporary folders.txt, this just came closest to working as intended.

```
set zip="P:\Programma's\x64\WINRAR\rar.exe" a -r -u -ep1
dir "%CD%" /d /ad /s /b > "%CD%\folders.txt"
set /a COUNT=0
pause
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in ("%CD%\folders.txt") do (
echo %%f
%zip% "%CD%\%%~nf.zip" %%f\* >nul
set /a COUNT+=1)
del "%CD%\folders.txt"
echo.
echo ....................................................
echo.
echo Compressed %COUNT% folders
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a variable to store it :

```
set cdfolder="%CD%\folders.txt"
```

then use it everywhere you need it

```
...
dir "%CD%" /d /ad /s /b > %cdfolder%
...
```

Comment: That's all it took to overcome the file name error. Thanks a bunch!